# Dialogflow: Edit/Delete Google Calendar events through Dialogflow Fulfilment

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How do I edit or delete Google Calendar events when the events is added through Dialogflow Fulfilment?

I followed through this tutorial : https://youtu.be/4_MvIf_ULgc to integrate Google Calendar with my current Dialogflow chatbot which is used as a ordering chatbot. However, I would need to delete or edits order bookings on Google Calendar. How do I do so? Can I use session entities on Dialogflow?

Thank you in advance for assisting me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions are best when they are trying to address a particular, specific, issues that you have attempted, but are having problems with. Updating your question to show us the code that you've tried, along with any error messages or illustrations of what isn't working, can help us help you. You may want to update your question, for example, to elaborate on why you think you need session entities, or how you want to use them. For more, see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)